# MySQL field type for specific point in time

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp, fieldtype

I am in need of a MySQL column that can store a specific date in time. The application I am working with gives me a UNIX timestamp (seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970). I need to store this information in the database and retrieve it later in specific ways, see below.

After this date has been stored I need to be able to query the database based on this timestamp. For example, I need to be able to retrieve all rows where the day of the timestamp is the 4th.

So then my question is how do I store this date where it would be easiest to perform the query? DATETIME and TIMESTAMP seem like valid options for me but I can't seem to figure out how to work the query. I am not looking forward to storing the timestamp as an integer as it wouldn't allow me to create such a query and I'd have to offload that work to PHP.

If it helps I need to deal with these timestamps in UTC time. I know TIMESTAMP will do the conversion into PST (my local time) for me and so I'd have to do the conversion back to UTC either in MySQL or PHP. (at least I think I would have to)

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'll save those data's as `DateTime`. The reasons are

- the records are readable with our own eye. eg `2013-01-04 00:25:12` is better than `1357259112`.
- you *don't have to use any conversion function* like [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to which i think kills the index. So it is much better to use `date` or `datetime` because you can utilize index since you can search the value directly by using `=` or `BETWEEN`

Comment: You have great points. I have one question for you, though. DATETIME is time zone independent correct? If I store a UTC datetime in a DATETIME field I can directly run DAY() on a row and get the day that row was in UTC time and not my local time zone?

Comment: since you mentioned that you store a UTC datetime, the value return from the day is from the UTC datetime save on the database.

Answer (score 0):

Store it as an `integer`, and then use MySQL's `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function as follows:

```
SELECT
    `field_list`
FROM
    `table_name`
WHERE
    FROM_UNIXTIME(`the_date`, '%d') = 4;
```

Comment: Couldn't I just as easily do FROM_UNIXTIME on the timestamp and then store it in a DATETIME and use DAY() to do the same thing? What would be the advantage of this method over that? I would prefer a date when browsing the database over a string of numbers.

Thanks!

Comment: You could, but this gives you the cleanest result in terms of the query. You didn't mention preferring dates over strings of digits in the question - why produce a timestamp if it's of no use to you?

Comment: Well in the interest of utility later down the line and overall cleanliness of the database I'd prefer a readable date. I also have to consider the time it would take to run FROM_UNIXTIME() on every row for every query rather than once when inserting it into the database. This point might be moot though considering I'd have to run DAY() on every row, every query. I couldn't say which would be faster or more reasonable with large queries.

My main issue is time zone problems but I believe DATETIME over TIMESTAMP might solve this problem.

Comment: This has probably been asked hundreds of times but can I just change the field of TIMESTAMP to DATETIME with no loss of data?